# Animated Sphere: How to connect bouncing followed by rolling on plane

Tags: animation

I am trying to make an animation where a sphere drops onto a plane, bounces slightly and then roles to a specific position on the plane.

For the dropping and bouncing I have tried soft body physics with the plane as a collision object.The goal is to have the sphere deformed just a little when hitting the plane.

For the rolling part I have tried a bezier curve from the point where the sphere comes to rest after dropping leading to the target position, using a follow path constraint for the sphere to follow the curve.
Both parts on their own work but I cant seem to get them connected. The sphere drops and bounces but then just sits there. I cant figure out how to make move along the curve afterwards.
Thank you!

Comment: Related question: [How to move / animate a soft body?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33805/107598)

Comment: Might be helpful: beginning with Blender 2.9.1( or .2?) most physics can be turned on/off with a "monitor" and "camera" icon in the viewport and in the render. For constraints, there is also an "eye" icon that can turn it on/off. To keyframe these switches hover them with the mouse and press `I` key.

Comment: @Blunder Thanks so much for your second comment, I was just at this moment searching for this when your comment came in. Fantastic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first bake your soft body animation into keyframes as it is described here: [How to bake softbody animation into keyframes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-to-bake-softbody-animation-into-keyframes)

And after that you can delete the soft body from your object and animate as you need it.

Comment: Thanks so much. After some initial trouble with the script in your link, I found this one, containing an updated script for Blender 2.91, whicj works like a charm: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35547/how-can-i-bake-vertex-animation-into-keyframes-but-make-sure-that-there-arent

Comment: Glad you could make it!